# How to get commaseparated input value as String[]? getParameterValues() returns single value

Tags: arrays, jsp, servlets

I have textbox which is having values seperated by comma. I want to get these each values printed in a line(one by one iterate) from Servlet class. But in my case all entire values is printing, i don't know the reason. how to solve this issue?

Here is the textbox in jsp page , with this form is submited:

```
<input id="LOAD_ID" placeholder="LOAD_ID" type="text" name="LOAD_ID" value="111,222,3333,">
```

In servlet:

```
final String[] strLoadID = request.getParameterValues(IConstants.LOAD_ID); 
 //dubugging >> values shows: 111,222,3333, 

for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    System.out.println(strLoadID[i]); // this is printing: 111,222,3333,
}
  /**
     But the Expected output is: 
                                  111
                                  222
                                  3333
  */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `getParameterValues` will retrieve the value of all the tags with such name/ID.

Since you only have one corresponding tag, you have an array of size one.

Here is a solution.

```
final String[] strLoadID = request.getParameterValues(IConstants.LOAD_ID); 
String[] load_idValues = strLoadID[0].split(",");

for (String s : load_idValues) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your servlet :-**

```
String strLoadID = request.getParameterValues(IConstants.LOAD_ID); 
String [] strArr = strloadID[0].split(",");
for(int i = 0 ; i < strArr.length ;i++){
   System.out.println(strArr[i]);
}
```